# Unable to build Android 11 Tinker Board 2/2S

Tags: android, makefile

I downloaded the source code for Android 11 for Tinker Board (S) R2.0 and Tinker Board 2/2S, from this link https://github.com/TinkerBoard/TinkerBoard/wiki . I tried to build the code using these commands given (in same link) :
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch WW_Tinker_Board_2-userdebug
./build.sh -UCKAu

during last step I got this error and it said build kernel failed. I don't know what to do, any help is appreciated,[build failed error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlwXm.png)  [cause of error (probably)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4C9ar.png)

I am new to android and I don't know what I can try to solve this problem.

Edit after comment :
I ran on wsl Ubuntu 22.04LTS, I have 200GB left after downloading the source code

Comment: I did a search on that error message and found possibly things to check. If you are using WSL there is [WSL #8045](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8045) and [WSL #8319](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8319). You should [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75418992/edit) with details your build environment (Windows/WSL, Linux (w/version), VM or not) and at least confirm you have downloaded the Android source code with >150 GB free space afterward.

Comment: Thank you @MorrisonChang the link you shared about WSL #8045 worked for me. !

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question with details as to what you did to fix your problem. Just don't add a link to the issue ticket without explaining what you followed from the issue ticket that resolved your problem.